# Capture certain parameters of URL in PHP

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching, pcre

I have the following code:

```
$url = 'http://www.domain.tld/go.jsp?a1=valuea1&b2=valueb2&c3=valuec3';
preg_match($regex, $url, $result);
```

I need a $regex that, applied to $url, returns in $result the same URL but only with the parameters selected in the regular expression. For example, a regular expression with an (alternative|selector) for the parameters that must be retrieved, along with the rest of URL. Of course, the name and values of parameters can be anything valid by the standard. The ? and & use in the result can be incorrect. For example, If I want to retrieve b2 and c3 parameters, this is valid:

```
'http://www.domain.tld/go.jsp&b2=valueb2&c3=valuec3'
```

Also, I know $result is an array, and I don't mind that the URL is 'distributed' among some items in it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What regex have you got so far?

Comment: I tried to use sub-patterns, but I'm not able to get the result I want. I only know a little about PCRE, and this is beyond my domains.

Comment: Can't solve something so you're going to use a regex? Well now you have two problems.

Comment: No, I need to use regular expressions, but I'm not an expert.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url) to get the query string part of the URL; and [`parse_str`](http://php.net/parse_str) to parse the query string:

```
$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query, $params);

var_dump($params);
```

You can manipulate $params as you want and re-assemble it into a query string with the [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/http_build_query) function:

```
$query = http_build_query($params);
```

---

Now, using a regex:

```
$url = preg_replace('/^
    ([^?#]+)            # everything except the query and #hash
    \?                  # the ?
    [^#]*?              # unwanted params
    \bparam_a=([^&#]+)  # param_a
    [^#]*?              # unwanted params
    \bparam_b=([^&#]+)  # param_b
    [^#]*?              # rest of query
    (\#.*)?             # optional #hash
    $/x', '\1?param_a=\2&param_b=\3\4', $url);
```

**This works only if param_a and param_b appear in this order**; prefer the parse_url/parse_str solution ;)

Comment: Because it's an "automated" process that can't be modified. It's like a "black box" that receives URLs and parameters, and returns the correct URLs. I can't modify it.

Comment: You can certainly replace `preg_replace($regex, $url, $result)` my `rewrite_my_url($url, $list_of_allowed_params)` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple proposal for a **single paramater** to filter so that you get the idea :

```
'/(.+?) # capture everything before the filtering parameter
([&\?]?) # takes care of the initial parameter prefix
(c3=[^&$]*)&? # capture the c3 parameter to filter
(.*) # captures the rest/mx'
```

Replacement string is :

```
 '$1$2$4'
```

There is a small caveat, if it captures the last parameter there will a trailing `&` too much, but you mentionned it was not a problem in your submitted question.

**Addition**
apply a preg_match for each parameter to filter.